# Why the state is not updating in App.js after setting up this.setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my simple to-do app program where I have made only one component which takes in the input form user and passes that input value to App.js to update items in App.js state.

**todo-form.component.js**

```
import React from 'react';


class SignInForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state ={
            temp: null
        };
}

    handleChange = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            temp: e.target.value
        },
        console.log(this.state)
        );
        // this.props.addInput(e.target.value);
    }

    handleSubmit= (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.temp);
        this.props.addInput(this.state.temp);

    }

    render(){
        return(
        <div className="container-form">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input 
            name="description" 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="add description"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.input}
            />

            <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>


        </div>

    );
}
}   


export default SignInForm;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SignInForm from './components/todo-form/todo-form.component'
import ItemList from './components/todo-list/todo-list.component';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
        input: []
    };
}
  addInput = (item)  => {
    let newInput=[...this.state.input,item];
    console.log(newInput);
    this.setState = ({
      input: newInput
    },
    console.log(this.state)
    );

  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
          <SignInForm addInput={this.addInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

On taking input the state inside **todo-form.component.js** is getting updated with the typed input value but on passing **state.temp** in **handleChange** function, the state inside App.js is not updating when **addInput** function is called.

Please help me on this issue and how my state is not getting updated in App.js??

Comment: did you try to pass props in constructor and super

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setState` is the problem. Have a look at my code.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    input: [],
  };
  addInput = (item) => {
    let newInput = [...this.state.input, item];
    //setState should be this way
    this.setState({
      input: newInput,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
        {this.state.input.map((el) => (
          <li> {el}</li>
        ))}
        <SignInForm addInput={this.addInput} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Login file.

```
class SignInForm extends React.Component {
  // constructor(props) {
  // super(props);
  state = {
    temp: null,
  };
  // }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      temp: e.target.value,
    });
    // this.props.addInput(e.target.value);
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.temp);
    this.props.addInput(this.state.temp);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-form">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="description"
            type="text"
            placeholder="add description"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.input}
          />

          <button type="submit">ADD</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignInForm;
```